# Parse time interval from text

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this data :

```
+-------------+----------------------------+
| name        | time_lost                  |
+-------------+----------------------------+
| Break000002 | 7 day 18.0 hours           |
| Break000003 | 0 day 10.0 hours           |
| Break000004 | 1 day 1.52 hours           |
| Break000005 | 2 day 21.0 hours           |
| Break000006 | 1 day 0.416666666667 hours |
| Break000007 | 0 day 1.25 hours           |
| Break000008 | 0 day 2.5 hours            |
| Break000009 | 1 day 0.02 hours           |
+-------------+----------------------------+
```

I want to calculate total time_lost in this table so I tried this:

```
select sum(time_lost) from mytable;
```

output:

```
+----------------+
| sum(time_lost) |
+----------------+
|             12 |
+----------------+
```

How can I parse this string to convert it into time?

Comment: Start by using a proper data type for the time_lost column.

Comment: There's nothing built-in to parse this, you'll need to write it yourself using `LOCATE()` and `SUBSTR()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the `time_lost` column to days with fractions like this:

```
LEFT(time_lost, LOCATE(' day', time_lost)-1) + SUBSTR(time_lost, LOCATE(' day', time_lost)+5)/24
```

Then put that into the `SUM()` function.

```
select sum(LEFT(time_lost, LOCATE(' day', time_lost)-1) + SUBSTR(time_lost, LOCATE(' day', time_lost)+5)/24) AS total_time_lost
from mytable;
```

The result for your sample data will be `14.2638 days`

Answer (score 2):

First use REPLACE function 2 times to remove "day " and "hours", and TRIM to remove the leading and trailing spaces

```
SELECT TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(time_lost, 'day ', ''), 'hours', ''))
```

Thus you will end up with this

```
| Break000002 | 7 18.0           |
| Break000003 | 0 10.0           |
| Break000004 | 1 1.52           |
| Break000005 | 2 21.0           |
| Break000006 | 1 0.416666666667 |
| Break000007 | 0 1.25           |
| Break000008 | 0 2.5            |
| Break000009 | 1 0.02           |
```

Then with SUBSTRING_INDEX you isolate the days (left part of string before the first space found)

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(time_lost, 'day', ''), 'hours', '')), ' ',1))
```

Which gives you this

```
| Break000002 | 7|
| Break000003 | 0|                    
| Break000004 | 1|                    
| Break000005 | 2|                    
| Break000006 | 1|                    
| Break000007 | 0|                    
| Break000008 | 0|                    
| Break000009 | 1
```

With SUBSTRING_INDEX and a negative count (-1) you can isolate the hours (right part of string before the first space found from the end)

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(time_lost, 'day', ''), 'hours', '')), ' ',-1))
```

Which gives you this

```
| Break000002 | 18.0           |                    
| Break000003 | 10.0           |                    
| Break000004 | 1.52           |                    
| Break000005 | 21.0           |                    
| Break000006 | 0.416666666667 |                    
| Break000007 | 1.25           |                    
| Break000008 | 2.5            |                    
| Break000009 | 0.02           |
```

You should also convert your results to numbers because they are actually considered strings

```
-- Days as unsigned integer                    
SELECT CAST(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(time_lost, 'day', ''), 'hours', '')), ' ',1)) AS UNSIGNED)                    

-- Hours with 2 digit precision                                                       
SELECT CAST(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(time_lost, 'day', ''), 'hours', '')), ' ',-1)) AS DECIMAL (2,2))
```

Now you are ready to make the computations

For the day, just SUM. 
For the hours you have to consider them as a fraction of a day : day = hours / 24

```
SELECT ( 
         SUM(CAST(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(time_lost, 'day', ''), 'hours', '')), ' ',1)) AS UNSIGNED))                                                             
       + SUM(CAST(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(time_lost, 'day', ''), 'hours', '')), ' ',-1)) AS DECIMAL (2,2)) / 24 )
       ) AS total_days
```

---

Edit: a bit too late

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to store the data as a unit of time in the first place. Maybe as a number of minutes, or number of seconds, depending on how accurately you need to measure it.

If you have the number of minutes, for instance, Then a "SUM" of the field will give you the total number of minutes in all the rows, and you can always convert it into hours/days/whatever for display by doing the appropriate multiplication or division - you can do that here, or perhaps it would be more appropriate in your application's presentation layer

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I can't do that. I have huge data, Just need to work on given string type data.

Comment: Ok. That's a shame. Maybe once you have a solution, you should consider replacing this column with the results of your query, for future use. Can you give a bit more detail? What unit of time would you like the SUM to be in? e.g. Days, Hours, minutes? Can the number of days ever go above 9 (i.e. 10 days would be an extra character to match). What level of accuracy is acceptable for the hours (the numbers are not all the same length - would the first four be sufficient, e.g. 18.0, or 0.41)?

Comment: Thanks for interest, here the days can go upto 2-digits i.e 0 - 99  and I am trying to get the overall time in minutes then display it in hh: mm format